# lstat function in Android JNI method

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk

I have something like this:

```
DIR *dir = opendir(curdir);
struct dirent *de = readdir(dir);
struc stat st;
lstat(de->d_name, &st);
```

I would like to know if `de` is a directory or a file, what should I do with st?

Comment: I guess you mean `de.d_name` in the call to `lstat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct and simple way is to check `if (de->d_type == DT_DIR)`.
You don't have to use `lstat` for that.